# alt tag for a background image

Tags: php, html, css

I want to place an alt tag for an image. But the image as in background. Not in the  tag. Is it possible in any way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Background images are, by definition, not part of the content and therefore it doesn't make sense to have alternative content for them. Don't abuse them to provide content and you don't need it.

Comment: I agree with @David Dorward.  The fact that you find yourself wanting an alt tag suggests it probably shouldn't be a background image at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible. But what i do for accessibility, (Sometimes you need to use icons that need to be accessible as well) is using a background image and placing a text in the element that has the background. And push out this content with a padding or a text-indent. It has the same effect then a alt tag for blind people.

Here an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/QTvUd/

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to use an attribute for a non-existent HTML element (an IMG, in your case). Is there something in particular you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to place an alt tag for an image. But the image as in background. Not in the tag

Nope.

If you are using CSS sprites, consider using an `img` as the container element. The `img` and `input type="image"` fields are the only ones that are allowed to have an `alt` property.